# Rspec how to determine if a let block has been defined?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

In Rspec, I want to take advantage of using `super()` to call a defined `let` block if it exists or set a new value if it hasn't, I want to use this within a `shared_example` group but I just can't find how to do this.

I've tried checking if `@some_let` exists, I've tried checking if a super method of `:some_let` is owned by the `kernel` or not and none of them provide anything useful; I can't access `instance_methods` or `instance_method` because Rspec won't let me and searching the internet for a method hasn't revealed an answer.

I want to be able to do something like this:

```rb
shared_examples 'a shared example' do
  let(:some_let) { let_exists?(:some_let) ? super() : some_new_value }
end
```

is there a method like `let_exists?` or something to that effect?

Comment: `if defined?(super)`, maybe?

Comment: `super` is always defined, the problem is that RSpec propagates `let` blocks so that each nested context has its own version of that `let` block, so it always exists once it's been defined. What's worse is Is can't even do something like `let(:let) { custom_defined_let || default_value }` because it would just error that `custom_defined_let` doesn't exist

Comment: `let(:some_let) { some_new_value } unless method_defined?(:some_let)` would work, i.e. only define the method if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: that wouldn't work as `some_let` only exists within the execution context, not in the complication context and like `instance_method` it's blocked :(

Comment: Not sure what you mean ... could you provide a more complete example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Code inside of `let`, `before`, `it` etc blocks are execution contexts in that they are executed as apart of each test. Other code around those blocks are complication contexts in that they "compile" the tests to be run. `method_defined?` is not available in execution contexts, i.e. `let`, `before`, `it` blocks, only compilation contexts such as `describe`. Doing what you suggested wouldn't work because `some_let` wouldn't exist.

Comment: I've posted an answer, it's a bit tedious to discuss this in the comments :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that you call `let` before including the shared examples, this would work:

```
shared_examples 'a shared example' do
  let(:some) { 'fallback value' } unless method_defined?(:some)
end

describe 'with let' do
  let(:some) { 'explicit value' }
  include_examples 'a shared example'

  it { expect(some).to eq('explicit value') }
end

describe 'without let' do
  include_examples 'a shared example'

  it { expect(some).to eq('fallback value') }
end
```

`method_defined?` checks if a method called `some` has already been defined in the current context. If not, the method is defined to provide a default value.

Another (usually easier) approach is to always define a default value and to provide the explicit value *after* including the shared examples: (thus overwriting the default value)

```
shared_examples 'a shared example' do
  let(:some) { 'default value' }
end

describe 'with let' do
  include_examples 'a shared example'   # <- order is
  let(:some) { 'explicit value' }       #    important

  it { expect(some).to eq('explicit value') }
end

describe 'without let' do
  include_examples 'a shared example'

  it { expect(some).to eq('default value') }
end
```

Comment: I'm surprised this works, but it does and I don't care beyond that, I can only surmise that some context is shared between execution and compilation, I thought it was more like say Chef where there is a compilation phase and an execution phase and they exist in seperate contexts and as such things like methods aren't shared between them.

Comment: @Thermatix RSpec creates a hierarchy of Ruby classes. Each `describe` creates a new class – the above code creates two classes: `RSpec::ExampleGroups::WithLet` and `RSpec::ExampleGroups::WithoutLet`. Calling `let` creates an instance method within that class. When running an example, RSpec creates an instance of the corresponding class which makes those instance methods become available to the example. The `describe` block as well as the `shared_examples` block correspond to the class body. And within a class body,  you can call `method_defined?` to check if a method was defined.